# passing sed backreference to base64 command

Tags: bash, unix, sed, base64, backreference

What I am trying to achieve is pass the Base64 encoded value captured in the `sed` regex to the `base64` and have it decoded.

But the problem is, even though it seems like the correct value is being passed to the function using backreference, `base64` complains that the input is invalid.

Following is my script -

```bash
#!/bin/bash
decodeBaseSixtyFour() { 
    echo "$1 is decoded to `echo $1 | base64 -d`"
}
echo Passing direct value ...
echo SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0Cg== | sed -r "s/(.+)$/$(decodeBaseSixtyFour SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0Cg==)/"
echo Passing captured value ...
echo SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0Cg== | sed -r "s/(.+)$/$(decodeBaseSixtyFour \\1)/"
```

And when ran it produces the following output -

```
Passing direct value ...
SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0Cg== is decoded to Hello Base64
Passing captured value ...
base64: invalid input
SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0Cg== is decoded to
```

I think the output explains what I mean.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? If not, why?

Comment: Shell will execute `decodeBaseSixtyFour` function before sed therefore it won't get back reference value.

Comment: @anubhava: But the last line in the output seem to suggest the values is passed. Can you explain what's going on?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: you're asking the question based on what you think the solution is. Tell us the "greater" problem you're trying to solve. For instance, why are you trying to cram sed into the answer?

Comment: @glennjackman: May be it's my lack of knowledge of shell scripting. Can you please explain why the last line in the output shows the captured value? And also the main target is the locate the base64 encoded values in a file and replace them with decoded values.

Comment: @BheshGurung You think it is passing your captured value but in reality it is passing `\\1` as the value to your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl `s///` can do what you want, but I don't think what you're asking for is what you need.

```
$ echo SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0Cg== | perl -MMIME::Base64 -pe 's/(.+)/decode_base64($1)/e'
Hello Base64
```

What's actually happening:

```
echo SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0Cg== | sed -r "s/(.+)$/$(decodeBaseSixtyFour \\1)/"
```

- Before sed starts reading input, the shell notices the process substitution in the double quoted string
- the `decodeBaseSixtyFour` function is called with the string `"\\1"`
- base64 chokes on the input `\1` and emits the error message
- the function returns the string `"\1 is decoded to "`
- now the sed script is `'s/(.+)$/\1 is decoded to /'` which is how you get the last line.

Comment: +1. `What's actually happening:` part is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BheshGurung: This is exactly what I meant in my first comment on your question but I couldn't explain this much in just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented sed cannot do an equivalent of `replace_callback` which is esentially what you're trying to do.

Following awk does close to what you're trying to do:

```
s="My string is SGVsbG8gQmFzZTY0Cg== something"
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i~/==$/) "base64 -D<<<"$i|getline $i}1'<<<"$s"
My string is Hello Base64 something
```