# Substitute values with ascii chars using sed

Tags: sed

We have files with some chars represented by decimal(!) ascii values enclosed in `cid(#)` as e.g. `(cid:104)` for `h`. The string `hello` is thus represented as `(cid:104)(cid:101)(cid:108)(cid:108)(cid:111)`.

How can I substitute this with the corresponding ascii characters using sed?

Here is an example file:

```
$ cat input.txt
first line
pre (cid:104)(cid:101)(cid:108)(cid:108)(cid:111) post
last line
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
$ x="(cid:104)(cid:101)(cid:108)(cid:108)(cid:111)"
$ echo $x | sed 's/(cid:\([^\)]*\))/\1/g'
104101108108111
```

But wee need the output to be `hello`

```
$ cat output.txt
first line
pre hello post
last line
```

I'm trying to use `printf` in `sed`. But cannot find out how to pass the backreference `\1` to `printf`

```
sed 's/(cid:\([^\)]*\))/'`printf "\x$(printf %x \1)"`'/g'
```

Comment: given your updated question, what is the exact, desired output? Note it is important to provide a [mcve] from the very beginning, since your update invalidates our current answers.

Comment: You might need to explain why 'using sed' is a requirement.  That is much, much more difficult than using a more suitable tool such as awk or perl...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat input.txt 
first line
pre (cid:104)(cid:101)(cid:108)(cid:108)(cid:111) post
last line

$ perl -pe 's/\(cid:(\d+)\)/chr($1)/ge' input.txt > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
first line
pre hello post
last line
```

Thanks @123 for suggesting to use `chr($1)` instead of `sprintf "%c", $1`. See [chr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) for documentation

Reference: [Integer ASCII value to character in BASH using printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890262/integer-ascii-value-to-character-in-bash-using-printf)

Comment: in our special case there are also "normal" characters. i.e. not all characters are represented as `(cid:#)` only some of them. I edit my original question to show an example file

Comment: can you also explicitly post how you want the output file to look with your sample input file? I will edit answer accordingly or delete

Comment: You can use `chr` instead of `sprintf`, i.e `perl -pe 's/\(cid:(\d+)\)/chr($1)/ge'`

Comment: @123 thanks :) ... didn't know about that function.. will edit the answer after OP clarifies his requirement

Comment: This does pretty much what I need. Thus +1. But I'd like to find a sed-only solution.

Comment: @wolfrevo That isn't going to happen.

Comment: @123 I'm trying to use printf in sed. But cannot find out how to pass the backreference `\1` to printf. sed 's/(cid:\([^\)]*\))/'`printf "\x$(printf %x \1)"`'/g'. See updated question.

Comment: @wolfrevo , I don't think that would be possible.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544044/passing-sed-backreference-to-base64-command

Answer (score 0):

Using `%c` you can convert an ASCII code into its corresponding character:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%c", 104}'
h
```

So it is a matter of extracting the numbers from within `(cid:XX)`. This I do by setting the FS to `(` and looping through the fields:

```
awk -v FS='(' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
                  r=gensub(/cid:([0-9]+)\)/, "\\1", "g", $i);
                  printf "%c", r+0
                  }
               }' file
```

This uses `gensub()` and accesses to the captured groups as described in [GNU awk: accessing captured groups in replacement text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1555441/1983854). Hence dependent on a GNU awk.

For your given input it returns:

```
$ awk -v FS='(' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {r=gensub(/cid:([0-9]+)\)/, "\\1", "g", $i); printf "%c", r+0}}' file
hello
```